# CustomDateEditor not working in Spring 4.1.6

Tags: spring

I am using a Date dob; field in my pojo class in spring 4.1.6 using maven
    below are the files associated with my app.

// this is my pojo class.

```
package com.aamir;

import java.util.Date;

public class Student {

private String firstName;
private Date dob;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public Date getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(Date dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}


}
```

// this is my client class

```
package com.aamir;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class ClientStud1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
    Student student = (Student) context.getBean("s1");

    System.out.println(student.getFirstName());
    System.out.println(student.getDob()); 

}
```

}
// and finally this is my beans.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="s1" class="com.aamir.Student">
       <property name="firstName" value="aamir"/>
       <property name="dob" value="12-12-1996"/>
   </bean>

    <bean id="dateEditor" 
               class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
                    <constructor-arg value="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
       <property name="customEditors">
         <map>
           <entry key="java.util.Date" value-ref="dateEditor"/>
         </map>
       </property>
   </bean>


</beans>
```

and I get this exception every time I try to run the client

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean     with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer#0' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'customEditors'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'customEditors[java.util.Date]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `PropertyEditor` are stateful, so you should not register instances directly.

- Register property editor **classes** via `customEditor` property
- Add `PropertyEditorRegistrars` via `propertyEditorRegistrars` property in `CustomEditorConfigurer`

As you want to configure the property editor instance, use property editor registrar instead.

```
    <bean id="customEditorConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
       <property name="propertyEditorRegistrars">
         <list>
           <bean class="org.example.CustomDateEditorRegistrar"/>
         </list>
       </property>
   </bean>
```

Comment: where can I get  propertyEditorRegistrars class

Comment: I am really confused which tag should I replace with the one u shown

Comment: I got it now, we have to create one class CustomDateEditorRegistrar

Comment: public class CustomDateEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

         public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry)          {
        registry.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"), false));
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

As per the official documentation , the recommended way of registering a `PropertyEditor` is to create a `class` that implements `propertyEditorRegistrar` interface. Each `propertyEditorRegistrar` can register any number of `propertyEditors` on a given `registry`.

Two such implementaions are descibed below:

**Approach 1: create a generalized class that implements `PropertyEditorRegistrar`.**

This class can be used for any `propertyEditor`(s), so you can keep this class in your utils.

Lets name it `CustomEditorRegistrar` and it looks like this:

```
public class CustomEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar
{
    Class<?>        t;
    PropertyEditor  propertyEditor;

    public CustomEditorRegistrar(Class<?> t, PropertyEditor propertyEditor)
    {
        this.t = t;
        this.propertyEditor = propertyEditor;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.registerCustomEditor(t, propertyEditor);
    }

}
```

. The bean definition to register a CustomDateEditor is as below:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
        <property name="propertyEditorRegistrars">
            <list>
                <bean class="mky.spring.property.editor.date.CustomEditorRegistrar">
                    <constructor-arg index="0">
                        <value type="java.lang.Class">java.util.Date</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg index="1">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor">
                            <constructor-arg index="0">
                                <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
                                    <constructor-arg value="dd-MM-yyyy" />
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                            <constructor-arg index="1" value="true" />
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean
        name="Customer"
        class="mky.spring.property.editor.date.Customer"
        p:name="Customer 1"
        p:address="CounterHills LA"
        p:deliveryDate="12-11-2016"
        p:issueDate="12-10-2016" />
```

Sys-out client:

```
public class TestGenericClient
{
    ApplicationContext  ctx;

    public TestGenericClient()
    {
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("genericPropertyEditorRegistrar-beans.xml");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(new TestGenericClient().ctx.getBean("Customer"));
    }
}
```

And the output is this:

```
Name=Customer 1
 Address=CounterHills LA
 Issue Date=Wed Oct 12 00:00:00 GST 2016
 deliveryDate=Sat Nov 12 00:00:00 GST 2016
```

**Approach2: create a specific propertyEditorRegistrar eg, for Date**

```
public class CustomDateEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar
{

    @Override
    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.registerCustomEditor(java.util.Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyyy"),true));
    }

}
```

And the bean declaration for this specific CustomDateEditor is :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
        <property name="propertyEditorRegistrars">
            <list>
                <bean class="mky.spring.property.editor.date.CustomDateEditorRegistrar" />

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Sys-out cleint:

```
public TestDateClient()
    {
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("datePropertyEditorRegistrar-beans.xml");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(new TestDateClient().ctx.getBean("Customer"));
    }
```

And the same output :

```
Name=Customer 1
 Address=CounterHills LA
 Issue Date=Wed Oct 12 00:00:00 GST 2016
 deliveryDate=Sat Nov 12 00:00:00 GST 2016
```